# Does this character have any Elvish blood?

Tags: shannara

Typically, users of the Elfstones have to have at least *SOME* Elvish blood. I can't recall in any book where this was not the case.

> In *Skaar Invasion*, Drisker uses the Black Elfstone to bring Paranor back. Is there any hint to him having Elvish lineage?

Comment: Uhl Belk did not have elven blood, although he is of course an ancient creature from the Age of Faerie.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At least [according to the wikia](http://shannara.wikia.com/wiki/Black_Elfstone), you don't need to have Elven blood to be able to use the Black Elfstone, so the character you mention doesn't necessarily have to have it:

> **Unique Properties**
>
> Unlike the blue Elfstones, the black Elfstone does not seem to need a sufficient amount of Elven blood to be used, nor does it need to be freely given. Despite Walker Boh's Elven blood being extremely thin, he uses the Elfstone with ease, with none of the problems Wil Ohmsford experienced with the stones. He is also able to use the Elfstone despite having forcibly taken it from Uhl Belk, unless one considers the fact that the Stone King allowed Walker to leave his dome without a struggle as a sign of consent.

Comment: Am I right in my recollection that there's never been a case of a non-Elvish blood using *any* Elfstone?

Comment: @MyCodeSucks - you're not wrong, but from the beginning, the Black Elfstone has been portrayed as an antithesis and an exception to pretty much everything known about Elfstones.